# Cross-eyed effect on Nvidia 3D Vision with three.js

Tags: three.js

I would like to ask you if there is some support or some plugin in `three.js` for 3D active glasses.

I have Nvidia 3D Vision active glasses and for my web application I need to implement cross-eye effect in tree.js.

Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Doing 3D stereo with active glasses is not a matter of plugin for three.js. If you read
[Active Shutter 3D System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_shutter_3D_system) you will see that you need a way to turn off the right eye while displaying the left eye followed by an off left eye which displaying the right eye content. So you need to synchronize the glasses with the display. And displays need to be of higher Herz than normal (ie. 60Hz) in order to be able to keep a real-time feel to the rendering. This limitation cannot be overcome in a browser window.